# Using ternary search to find all elements within a range?

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I'm looking for algorithm with an average case performance of O(log(N)), to extract the elements are between (or equal to) a min and a max value from a sorted list.

The issue being that since the the min and max values may not actually be in the list, or perhaps even repeated, a binary search won't do. Ternary search seems to be closer to what I seek, but I haven't been able to create a function that does what I see based on ternary search so far.

For example, the input:

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], min=3, max=6
```

Should return [3,4,5,6]. Likewise,

```
list=[500,757,2412,10000,123123], min = 600, max = 5000
```

Should return [757,2412].

This could  also be done in python less efficiently using:

```
def withinRange(values,min,max):
   return [val for val in sorted(values) if val <= max and val >= min]
```

The operation is called enough that a O(log(N)) is very much preferred, and the sorting will only be done once.

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning in *"since the the min and max values may not actually be in the list, or perhaps even repeated, a binary search won't do"*. Could you elaborate?

Comment: It needs to be a binary search with memory. "Remember the last value you had. If you are about to return 'value not found', return that last value in your memory"

Comment: In the lower example, the algorithm was intended to return all values within the list between the min and max values. A less efficient way to do the same thing is: [x for x in list if x >= min and x <= max]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> def bin_slice(L, min, max):
...     i = bisect.bisect_left(L, min)
...     j = bisect.bisect(L, max)
...     return L[i:j]
... 
>>> bin_slice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3, 6)
[3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> bin_slice([500,757,2412,10000,123123], 600, 5000)
[757, 2412]
```

The complexity is something like 2log(N) which is O(log(N)). Also note that `bisect` may use a C implementation for `bisect` which will be faster than anything you can write in pure-python, so a pure-python solution will probably be slower even if doing a bit less comparisons.

You could optimize slightly the search for `j` passing the `lo` parameter to `bisect`:

```
j = bisect.bisect(L, max, i)
```

Comment: That might be what I'm looking for. I'll see if anything else comes up, either way, that module looks like it'll be useful for additional things I'm working on related to this question.