# matching line segments - robust and fast way

Tags: c++, image-processing, vector, pattern-matching, computational-geometry

I have 2D line segments extracted from a single image data and would like to match with 3D line segments extracted from other source. for that, first I would like to project a 3D line segment to the image space using co-linearity equation (I know exterior orientation parameters). AS both line segments are in same coordinate system now I would like to find the best matching line segment to that line.

I am looking for a fast and robust algorithm to match corresponding line segments in order to update my 3D line segments later.

If any one have an idea on this, please give some suggestions. thanks in advance.

Comment: you should have somewhere a projection matrix that convert the 3d world coordinates to screen coordinates. Could you post more about this?

Comment: @Felice Pollano: Actually, I have known interior, exterior orientation parameters. So, my idea is to use col-linearity equation to convert 3D coordinates to image coordinates or vise versa. then I have either 2D or 3D line segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at a problem similar to [line segment intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment_intersection_problem). So unsuprisingly, it's solutions are probably similar as well.

The straightforward approach would be to compare each 2D segment to each 3D segment, best match is the one that most closely corresponds to the predicted length and position when compared to the actual. The actual being the 2D segments. That's something like O(AB), where A is the number of 2D segments and B is the number of 3D segments.

You can speed up the method somewhat by sorting the 2D segments lexicographically, then use the same kind of algorithm I asked about in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507766/using-ternary-search-to-find-all-elements-within-a-range) to obtain all line segments whose x values are within a certain amount to the expected x value of one or both of the line segments end point*. In the worst case, you could still run into O(AB), but the average time should be closer to O(B log A). Although, it's not clear as to if you can use this method based on what you've said, so this paragraph should be considered more of an outline.

Faster than O(B log A) or O(A log B) is likely to require this to be a well researched problem.

- You can probably get away with 1 end point, if you lexicographically sort the 2D endpoints.

Comment: @M C: thanks for the response. If I say, if i want to match 2D line segments, obtained from two data sources or 2 images then which method would be the best as even the 2 corresponding line may be not in same location and lengths, and slightly different orientation, and so on. thanks

Comment: I was more less assuming that you would handle each image separately. So the times then become O(A_1B + A2B) and O(B log A1 + B log A2). If you've already combined the segments, you should be able to pick them apart in O((A1+A2)B) and O(B log (A1+A2)) by looking for the best fit to each orientation. Although the best fit part might be more difficult in that case. In any case, either algorithm will probably work fine, although the faster one may be slightly more prone to error if your orientation is off.

Comment: Oh and the binary search method should work both ways. You probably have more 3D lines segments than you do 2D lines segments. Although the resulting size of the range of line segments is likely to be more. Although overall, that method might work better if the number of 3D points is significantly more, like (A1+A2) < sqrt(B).